# MYSQL Time Comparison Range

Tags: mysql, time, comparison, range

I'm trying to help a taxi company. The problem is that they have a credit card machine that takes payments, and has its own database entries, and there is a completely separate database that has a list of entries such as pick up time, and drop off time.

I need to match the database of trip entries to the credit card purchases, and the only way to do this is by matching which vehicle is running the transaction, and looking for a time CLOSE TO the DROP OFF time and see if it's a match. It's not ideal.

So, I am trying to compare two times in `yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format. They need to be plus or minus 5 minutes of each other. How do I do this in MYSQL?

I thought SubTime and Addtime would work, and it seemed to, but then I got wierd results.

SELECT * FROM completedtrans WHERE DrivID = 128 AND TransTime BETWEEN SUBTIME('2013-06-20 16:53:06', '0 00:05:00') AND ADDTIME('2013-06-20 16:53:06', '0 00:05:00')

Here's an example of one of my searches. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? It's supposed to search 5 minutes before and after that particular given time. I can't simply write the time, because the query is automatically generated through php code.

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col) gives you the unix timestamp of a date or column which is an integer, with that you can easily compare dates

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to the question rather than a comment. Many people search for only "unanswered" questions on SO to answer.

Comment: I still need help after all.